# Request Password Reset for Email using Swift Parse Server and AWS SES

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, parse-server, amazon-ses

I got AWS SES to work with Parse server using

```
$ npm install parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter --save
```

After changing server.js and setting verifyUserEmails: true I was able to get the verify user emails sending out and the click seting it to true.

I then added my swift code for reset password and was encouraged that when I 
entered an email that wasn't user it knew and returned an error.  When I put a valid user in no error, but also no email...

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: userName.text!) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
    if success {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Please check your email and follow the instructions", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        alert.addAction(ok)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
}
```

Am I possibly missing something that I need to add in the server.js?  I have the html and text template in the proper location just like for the verify user.  I scoured the internet thinking maybe there was something like the verifyUserEmails setting but I can't figure out what turns that functionality on.  Can anyone help?  If I can't get this to work I will have to start all over again with mailgun.

This is my server.js for reference:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
    appId: "c4f3ec***************",
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
    publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
    verifyUserEmails: true,
    appName: process.env.APPNAME,
    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)
    filesAdapter: {
        "module": "@parse/s3-files-adapter",
        "options": {
            "bucket": process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        }
    },
    emailAdapter: new AWSEmailAdapter({
        // The address that your emails come from
        fromAddress: process.env.EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: 'us-east-1',
        // The template section
        templates: {
            passwordResetEmail: {
                subject: 'Reset your password',
                pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, './email_templates/password_reset_email.txt'),
                pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, './email_templates/password_reset_email.html'),
                callback: (user) => {
                    return {
                        firstName: user.get('firstName')
                    }
                }
                // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
            },
            verificationEmail: {
                subject: 'Confirm your account',
                pathPlainText: resolve(__dirname, './templates/verification_email.txt'),
                pathHtml: resolve(__dirname, './templates/verification_email.html'),
                callback: (user) => {
                    return {
                        firstName: user.get('firstName')
                    }
                }
                // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
            },
        }
    }),
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness I thought of just deleting this question because the solution was so embarrassing, but decided I would just answer it here in case any one else has a similar question and my code snippet (and mistake) would be instructive.

In the server.js that I included above everything was actually set up properly for the most part.  The reason that the verify emails were going out and the reset passwords ones were not was because I changed the path for the email templates and only had the correct one on verify (./templates vs ./email_templates).  So in short, I corrected that path, saved the changes to server.js, and then ran pm2 restart 0 to restart the server and voila, passwords are resetting!